# Where can I find a cheap VoIP gateway that support VPNs?

Tags: vpn, router

I have a physical SIP phone for my home office that I would like to use with my company's VOIP system. The problem though is that the only way I could get it to work is if it can connect to my company's VPN.  The phone doesn't offer that option.

I'd like to know if there's a 1 port VPN gateway/router I could use for it that supports IPSEC. I'd like to use that rather than have my entire home network always connected to the company VPN.

I'm not interested in any bells and whistles... just something fast and easy (that is low on power).  I know OpenBSD is an option but that would I'd have to have an extra server running.

Most of the wired VPN routers I've seen allow you CREATE VPN tunnels... but not join one that's already setup.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few years ago, I was able to get a [Linksys BEFVP41](http://www.linksysbycisco.com/US/en/products/BEFVP41) to connect via IPsec to a Cisco VPN gateway, so that's possibly an option. If you want a bit more flexibility, I'd recommend forking out a bit of money for an [Alix 2D3](http://www.pcengines.ch/alix2d3.htm) (or another similar model) and run Pfsense on it. Pfsense will give you all you need as far as VPN and *much* more functionality than the Linksys router will give you. The 2D3 board with case and power supply will run somewhere around 150 USD.

Answer (score 1):

I do believe that the [Cisco ASA 5505](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/security/asa-firepower-services/index.html) will fit your circumstances.  It's relatively inexpensive (for a Cisco product) and is easy to set up.

[image]
<sub>(source: [cisco.com](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/i/100001-200000/190001-200000/190001-191000/190930.jpg))</sub>